# Testing CSS animations performance (CPU time)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, performance-analysis

I am trying to do some performance test for pure CSS animations vs JS animations (Velocity or raw JS). The chrome profiling tool is a great tool to test JavaScript CPU usage, however it tests only JavaScript, and seems to ignore CSS animations completely.

Is there any tool that monitors CPU time for micro processes as such, and breaks down the results?